# How to clip the corners of Positioned widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-positioned

Here is the output which I am getting:

[image]

I want to clip the green Positioned widget on corners with that of grey Container's rounded corners.
Any Help will be highly appreciated.

My current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CustomCard(
          title: 'Custom Card', percentage: 50.0, color: Colors.green),
    );
  }
}

class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final double percentage;
  final Color color;
  CustomCard(
      {required this.title, required this.percentage, required this.color});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer, children: [
          Container(
            height: 100.0,
            width: width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: -(percentage / 100) * width,
            top: -(percentage / 100) * width,
            child: Container(
              height: (percentage / 100) * width * 2,
              width: (percentage / 100) * width * 2,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.circular(((percentage / 100) * width)),
                color: color,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: you cant do that, but instead of `Stack` use `Container` (grey) with `clipBehavior` that clips the child `Container` (green)

Comment: I tried it. not working. May be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @KetanRamteke you can wrap your `Stack` in a `ClipRRect` and then set the borderRadius of ClipRRect to 10

Comment: @pskink I am getting this output: https://imgur.com/a/5eJbY3J

Comment: Thank you pskink for helping, @TheAlphamerc fixed the issue. Really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ketan if you wrap the Stack with `ClipRRect1 widget and provide it a border radius then it will add border to both green and gray area.

```dart
class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final double percentage;
  final Color color;
  CustomCard({this.title, this.percentage, this.color});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer, children: [
              Container(
                height: 100.0,
                width: width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: -(percentage / 100) * width,
                top: -(percentage / 100) * width,
                child: Container(
                  height: (percentage / 100) * width * 2,
                  width: (percentage / 100) * width * 2,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.circular(((percentage / 100) * width)),
                    color: color,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that just using ClipRRect, Check the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CustomCard(
          title: 'Custom Card', percentage: 50.0, color: Colors.green),
    );
  }
}

class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final double percentage;
  final Color color;
  CustomCard(
      {required this.title, required this.percentage, required this.color});
  
  Widget positionedWidget(double width){
   return Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer, children: [
          Container(
            height: 100.0,
            width: width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: -(percentage / 100) * width,
            top: -(percentage / 100) * width,
            child: Container(
              height: (percentage / 100) * width * 2,
              width: (percentage / 100) * width * 2,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
               
                color: color,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]
      );
    
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: ClipRRect(borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(30),
      child: positionedWidget(width))));
  }
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank You Mohan for answering, it kinda works but I was hoping to get smoother rounded edges like the parent grey container.

Comment: You can do that by adjusting border radius

Comment: @KetanRamteke Answer Updated

Comment: yes, looks wonderful, but as TheAlphamerc replied with correct ans before, I had to accept his answer. Upvoted though :) Once again, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final double percentage;
  final Color color;
  CustomCard(
      {required this.title, required this.percentage, required this.color});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          child: Stack(children: [
            Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: width,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: -(percentage / 100) * width,
              top: -(percentage / 100) * width,
              child: Container(
                height: (percentage / 100) * width * 2,
                width: (percentage / 100) * width * 2,
                color: color,
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]